# Is there any option for natively playing Quake 2 on OS X 10.7 and above?

Tags: macos, quake-2

How can I play natively Quake  2 on OS X 10.7 or above?

Comment: Wasn't the source code to Q2 released ages ago?

Comment: Yes but without art, and I think that is not just compile the code and run...IF compiles in current systems.

Comment: You're going to have to legally acquire the data files one way or another -- I think the game's on steam, come to think of it. gaming.stackexchange.com will not help you pirate games.

Comment: Of course, i'm talking about running the game, not pirate the game.

Comment: Install yamagi quake, then copy the .pak files to the directory as per the installation instructions. Done.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: I don't actually have OS X myself, but...

[Yamagi Quake](http://www.yamagi.org/quake2/) seems to be the most popular port of the quake 2 source code -- and the most recent release includes OSX support. You'll need the data files from the original CD to actually play, of course, but that's beyond the scope of this site.